# Will CRM SOAP Messages Be Identical in 2013 and D365?

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

If there is a service that is creating custom SOAP messages, currently communicating to a CRM 2013 on prem, and the CRM system gets upgraded to D365 (v.8.2) on prem, will the soap messages still work?

Is there some change to either the SOAP namespace or structure that will be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages will still work, because Microsoft did not change the service contract. E.g. a Javascript library I designed a few years (versions) earlier depends on the SOAP endpoint. It still works on version 8.2 without modifications. it all comes down to using the proper XML namespaces.